# Showing Weekly totals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a report that shows the total time used in a week. I have only been successful in showing the total used by day using the formula below:

```
select left(report_date, 11) as week_start,
       case
         when id is null then
          'Enterprise'
         else
          id
       end id,
       case
         when id in ('CN','NQ','AR','DA','PR','FM') then
          'West'
         when id = 'Enterprise' then
          'ALL'
         else
          'East'
       end as Region,
       sum(actual_seconds) / 3600 as Actual_Hours,
       sum(goal_seconds) / 3600 as Goal_Hours,
       sum(goal_seconds * 1.0) / nullif(sum(actual_seconds * 1.0), 0) * 100 as Performance
  from summary_table
 where report_date > '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'
 group by rollup(id), report_date
 order by report_date
```

I would also like to have totals for 'East' and 'West' if possible.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Add your expression for `Region` to the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to do anything...

Comment: Grouping by week number could work -> DATEPART(WEEK,report_date) as week_no?

Comment: I would add region (not doing any math yet) to a sub query and then do the math in the outer query and then you should be able to group by region. But weird how grouping by it now doesnt work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Some sample data and the expected results based on that sample would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to summarize by week but still having issues adding totals by region.

```
Select
    dateadd(day, -(datepart(weekday, report_date) + 6 ) % 7, report_date) as week_start, 
   case
         when id is null then
          'Enterprise'
         else
          id
       end id,
       case
         when id in ('CN','NQ','AR','DA','PR','FM') then
          'West'
         when id = 'Enterprise' then
          'ALL'
         else
          'East'
       end as Region,  
        sum(actual_seconds)/3600.0 as Actual_Hours,
        sum(goal_seconds)/3600.0 as Goal_Hours,
        sum(goal_seconds*1.0)/NULLIF(sum(actual_seconds*1.0),0)*100 as performance 
    from     summary_table
    where        dateadd(day, -(datepart(weekday, report_date) + 6 ) % 7, report_date) >= 
                      dateadd(day, -365 - datepart(dw, getdate()), getdate())
    group by    dateadd(day, -(datepart(weekday, report_date) + 6 ) % 7, report_date), rollup(id)
```